# Range proofs and Groth-Sahai PPEs

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, pairings, verifiable-random-function

I'm looking for a set of pairing product equations (ala Groth-Sahai) which allow a prover to prove that the output of a VRF is in a specific range.

In the E-cash system in [[BCKL]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-03298-1_9) there is a construction of VRF which basically outputs a weak Boneh-Boyen signature. But this signature is a group element in source group 1 ($\mathbb{G}_1$).

Is there a way to "transform/encode" the output as an element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and subsequently prove that it falls in a specific range (using the an approach like [CCS08](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2008/53500238/53500238.pdf))?

Comment: What do you mean by "range" in $\mathbb{G}_1$?

Comment: AFAIK the output of the [BCKL]-VRF is a pseudorandom element $y\in\mathbb{G_1}$.
The goal is to interpret this element, $y$, as an integer or a bit-string in order to subsequently prove that the random element is in a specific range (say $0\leq y<H$).

Alternatively find another VRF construction that lends itself well to GS but outputs (directly) $y\in Z_p$.